# Components bundling to separate files, so they can plugged into main file to work

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When using react-native command line tools to create a bundle. And using that bundle for Integration to the existing Android/iOS app.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
index.android.js --bundle-output [some-file-name]
```

Is it possible to separate output files, So that I can load them remotely?

**Example:**

I have 2 components in React native app.

If I use above command it creates one bundle file and I have to copy that into the Android package and bundle it and create .apk file.

What I am looking for is, The output should contain, one **Base File** with all that core **react native** code and 2 separate files for the **2 components** each. So I can host the **2 components** on the server, and Core **Base File** on the Android. Then, when required, I will load the component from the remote server into Android ReactRootview.

Same should apply to iOS as well.